# Planning short trip to Mozambique from Swaziland, visa questions

Tags: visas, mozambique

I am planning a day (or two) trip to Mozambique from Swaziland. I will just be in Maputo and will enter via a bus from Swaziland. I've seen that since I am a US citizen I require a visa to enter Mozambique. I am about to go through the process but have some initial questions.

On the [instructions](http://mozambique.travisa.com/) and [form](http://mozambique.travisa.com/PDFFiles/mozambique_visa.pdf) I see it requires a business letter, proof of departure, and hotel confirmation. I have none of those since I am just going for leisure, will be arriving on a bus, and was just planning on finding a hotel when I arrive.

Are these deal breakers for obtaining a visa?

Also, how long does the visa process take for Mozambique?

Edit: I see for a tourism visa the business letter isn't needed. But the itinerary and hotel reservations are still required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated on the Mozambique High Commission's website and just about every other visa processing website ... "Applicants **MUST** submit the following" ... and that following list includes: Copy of flight itinerary; Hotel booking confirmation.  So yes not having those two pieces will be a deal breaker.  Most Embassies for African countries are sticklers for the rules.

edited .. proof of overland transport in and out usually will substitute for an air itinerary, but not sure how you would prove a booking on a public bus.

Comment: This has always had me curious as I find it hard to believe that African countries suffer greatly from people entering and never leaving.

Comment: Western countries are tough on Africans seeking visas to visit and so a little reciprocity comes into play.  But they can't afford to deny visas as they need the western cash flow, so they just make us jump through some hoops to get there.